# MySQL - have a separate id for each category

Tags: php, mysql

My table looks like this:
[image]

So in PHP I have the following:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM siteData WHERE category = '$temp_cat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");
// db_query() is a custom function which executes mysqli queries to the db
```

I'm displaying the `id` in my post HTML and use it as a permalink to the post. That's all good, but when I decide to filter by category I see the following:

> `Main page`:
>
> -Post Title-
>
> -2- <-- Post ID
>
> -Post Content-
>
> -Post Footer-
>
> ---
>
> -Post Title-
>
> -1- <-- Post ID
>
> -Post Content-
>
> -Post Footer-
>
> `About Page`:
>
> -Post Title-
>
> -4- <-- Post ID
>
> -Post Content-
>
> -Post Footer-
>
> ---
>
> -Post Title-
>
> -3- <-- Post ID
>
> -Post Content-
>
> -Post Footer-

And so on... What I mean with this is that posts have misleading IDs that are set upon post creation and automatically increase. This leads to `About Page` beginning with post that has `id = 3` and not `id = 1`. Is there any possible way to make it count IDs for different categories separately?

Comment: I'm just beginning to understand SQL, can you show me an example query?

Comment: Each category has its own page. All of these pages display the posts `WHERE category = "something"`... But the posts are ordered by `id` which means I will create a post in `category 1` and it will have `id = 1`, for example. Then I will create a post for `category 2` and it will have `id = 2` because `id = AUTO_INCREMENT`. The problem here is that there is only **1** post in `category 2` so it shouldn't have `id = 2`. I hope I made it more clear for you.

Comment: I guess my database structure is to blame for the above behavior... If there is any way to rearrange the columns in the DB or better yet - a PHP way to fix it I'd be happy to accept it as this question's answer.

Comment: cat 2 id 2 sounds great to me the way you have it. It appears to be a presentation issue to you.

Comment: If you want a ranking answer so that each category goes 1 to N in all cases without gaps (UX) then you can do that. But cat 2 id 2 for the only one under cat 2 is the most important thing to keep. You don't want to go rejuggle everything (including the id's in other tables) when gaps occur such as deletes.

Comment: It is a presentation issue indeed. But imagine I have 1 post in `category 1`  with `id = 1` and 7 posts in `category 2`. Then I create a second post for `category 1` which will have `id = 9`. The user reads: `post 1 -> post 9` in that category. In the other -` post 2 -> post 7`. That's what I'm trying to fix...

Comment: I have only one table -- it's a simple blog for a high-school project. The posts I've already made are for testing purposes only so deleting them wouldn't be a problem - I can reset the `id`. So do you have any idea whether what I'm asking for is even possible at all?

Comment: I see no problem with presenting [This](http://i.imgur.com/E1D8Qhi.jpg) to a user. I think you are spending too much thought on this one

Comment: Well I could just hide the `id` from the user too... But in the admin panel there is a page, `select.php` where the admin writes the `id` and the form sends it to `edit.php`. Since only the `id` can't have repeating data I decided to use it for selecting posts that need to be edited. So how would you advice me in this situation? I imagine there is a way to make, for example the post `title` not contain repeating data, then I can hide the `id` and let the admin choose from a list of post `title`s?

Comment: But this doesn't look like a good solution to me... The other option is to remove the `edit.php` page altogether and leave only `post.php` :(

Comment: [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat room if you want. I have said all I can above.

Comment: presumably this has been solved: [chat link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34323070#34323070)

Comment: Yes, it has. Maybe add an answer so I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: Johny you created your own answer so do a self-answer we can accept and upvote.

Comment: Well, I can accept it in 2 days X'D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion, this is what I have in my `select.php` file:

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $date = $row['date'];
?>
        Category: &#8220;<?php echo $category; ?>&#8221;
        &#160;<span class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>&#160;
        Title: <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" hreflang="en">&#8220;<?php echo $title ?>&#8221;</a>
        &#160;<span class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>&#160;
        Date: <time datetime="<?php echo $date; ?>"><?php echo $date; ?></time><br>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I then `SELECT` the post by the `id` which I `$_GET` from the URI and display some `form`-specific elements that hold the post values. Then I update the data in the db.